# Discriminating endpoints based on Accept header

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an endpoint which returns a certain set of data. The front end may want this data either as a csv, or as a json object that it can manipulate further. I'm trying to use the value of the Accept header sent by the front end to determine which method to use to return the required data, so in my controller I have these methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("text/csv")]
    [Route("{id:Guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(Guid id)
    {
        // foo
    }
```

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("{id:Guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetJson(
        [FromRoute] Guid id,
        [FromQuery(Name = "page[Limit]")] ushort pageLimit = 25,
        [FromQuery(Name = "page[Offset]")] ushort pageOffset = 0)
    {
        // bar
    }
```

When I try to call the endpoint, though, I get `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.`, and a 500 response. The request I'm sending definitely has an `Accept: text/csv` header on it, but my controller apparently isn't using that to determine which method to use. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A single endpoint can produce multiple outputs (default is JSON). [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#the-accept-header-2) should help.